# package xxx/xxx/xxx is not in GOROOT error while setting up GO workspaces

Tags: go

I have a project structure like below:

```
apiv3
    - model
    - controller
    -view

apps
    - app1
    - app2
    - app2
```

apps package is used inside apiv3 with import path like apps/app1

I created a workspaces using the steps described here: https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces

**GO ENV OUTPUT:**

**go version: 1.18.3**

```
GO111MODULE="on"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/pc6/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/pc6/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/home/pc6/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/pc6/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.18.3"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
GOWORK="/home/pc6/workspace2/go.work"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build1440253706=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

When I hit `go run apiv3` inside the workspace directory, it says:

`package apps/app1 is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/apps/app1)`

Comment: What is the full path to your project root directory?  If your project is at ${GOROOT}/myproject, with the subdirectory structure as you've described above, you would import as `import "myproject/apps/apps1"`.

Comment: The project is not at ${GOROOT}/myproject. I am setting up workspaces so it is in the /home/user/workspace/myproject

Comment: I mistyped - using the model I was describing, the project would be at `${GOROOT}/src/myproject`

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1

In this solution, I shall assume that the way to project is built is following this structure :

```
project
|
├─apiv3 
|  ├─model
|  ├─controller
|  └─view
└─apps
   ├─app1
   ├─app2
   └─app2
```

In the folder `project`, run `go mod init project`.

Now, when code in `apiv3` calls imports from `apps`, replace `apps/apps1` by `project/apps/apps1`

You may replace "project" by anything. I recommend the url of your remote repository, so that it may be accessed on machines that don't store the source files.

#### Solution 2

Optionally, you can also run `go mod` in both `apiv3` and `apps`.